# What I need to do to change button image from method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I use this: if thisbid(int) equals to buildingid1, then thisb is control of brick1 (this is button). Then I need to change picture of button but with thisb, because I have 30+ picures, so I don't want spend my time for nothing.

This is what I tried to do:

```
public void Get_Block_Images()
{
    if (thisbid == buildingid[1])
    {
        var thisb = this.Controls.Find("brick1", true);
    }
    else if (thisbid == buildingid[2])
    {
        var thisb = this.Controls.Find("brick2", true);
    }

    switch (thisbid)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            thisb.Image = brick_def_1;
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            thisb.Image = brick_def_white;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            thisb.Image = brick_stan_nature;
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            thisb.Image = brick_stan_pixel;
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            thisb.Image = brick_stan_black_gold;
            break;
        }
        //etc...
```

Comment: How do you expect to be able to access `thisb` if it isn't in the same scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short what you need to do is move the `thisb` variable so that it is within the same scope as the switch statement. For example, you'll need to do something like the following of placing this line above the if statements:

```
var thisb = new Button();
```

On a side note your checking the `thisbid` in the if statements and the switch statement. Why not just merge them together?